# Crystal Reports Sort different on server vs Visual Studio

Tags: crystal-reports

We are coding many reports in Crystal using the Visual Studio 2010 plug in.  We're hosting the web application on Win Server 2008 Enterprise 64bit.  We use SQL to sort the data being sent to the report.

The issue: On some reports the order is different on the server than when developing using VS.  We're hitting the same DB in both cases and have confirmed that the data table being passed to the report is the same in both cases.  We've confirmed that the DLLs are the same between the environments.  We have a workaround which is to dictate the sort in the report.  That seems like overkill.

Any ideas?

Thanks ST

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely either record sort criteria in the reports or groups.

Both of these would override any ordering handled at db level.

Comment: Reasonable thought.  However, it doesn't explain why the report sorts differently in 2 different environments.  Run the report from the workstation via VS, sort is correct.  Take those same compiled files, put them on the server and run from there, you get a different sort.

Comment: I take it that the reports where this is happening have no ordering within Crystal Reports?

If so, could the problem lie with regional settings being different between the PCs?